# No visible @interface for 'DetailViewController' declares the selector 'setItem:'

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a drill-down interface and pass the data between my two controllers.

Once I implement my method, it keep get me this error

```
No visible @interface for DetailViewController declares the selector 'setItem'
```

I did the property on one of my controller, and I imported the controller to the other one.

Am I doing something wrong?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];

NSArray *items = [[SBACCItemStore sharedStore] allItems];
PeopleItem *selectedItem = [items objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];


//No visible @interface for 'DetailViewController' declares the selector 'setItem:'
[detailViewController setItem:selectedItem];

[[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];

}
```

I have a property `People *item` in DeatailController, I also import it in `itemViewController`.

Comment: Where did you declare the property in DetailViewController, .h or .m ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. It disappeared when I placed the property declaration for 'item' in DetailViewController in the .h file instead of the .m file. I think this makes the item public and visible to the other controllers.

@property (nonatomic,strong) BNRItem *item;

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared the People proptery like this in your header file?

@property (nonatomic, strong) People *item;